# Using the Solr Terms Component for an Auto-Suggest Feature

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to use the terms component as described [in the Solr docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Terms+Component) (see *Using the Terms Component for an Auto-Suggest Feature*).

### Prerequisite

Running Solr 6.3.0.

I currently have 4 docs in my index:

```js
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1482239790124"}},
  "response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "title":["There's nothing better than a shiny red apple on hot summer day."],
        "_version_":1554244409915080704},
      {
        "id":"2",
        "title":["Eat an apple!"],
        "_version_":1554244409917177856},
      {
        "id":"3",
        "title":["I prefer a Grannie Smith apple over Fuji."],
        "_version_":1554244409917177857},
      {
        "id":"4",
        "title":["Apricots is kinda like a peach minus the fuzz."],
        "_version_":1554244409917177858}]
      }
}
```

My field definition looks like this (otherwise my scheme.xml is vanilla):

```java
<field name="title" type="strings" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

My terms component is default (as is my whole solarconfig.xml):

```java
<searchComponent name="terms" class="solr.TermsComponent"/>

<requestHandler name="/terms" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <bool name="terms">true</bool>
    <bool name="distrib">false</bool>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>terms</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

### The Problem

When doing a request like `http://localhost:8983/solr/test/terms?terms.fl=title&terms.prefix=ap`, I'm expecting the following in return:

```xml
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">1</int>
  </lst>
  <lst name="terms">
    <lst name="title">
      <int name="apple">3</int>
      <int name="Apricots">1</int>
    </lst>
  </lst>
</response>
```

But what I actually get is an empty response.

When I instead do `http://localhost:8983/solr/test/terms?terms.fl=title&terms.prefix=Ea` I get:

```xml
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">0</int>
  </lst>
  <lst name="terms">
    <lst name="title">
      <int name="Eat an apple!">1</int>
    </lst>
  </lst>
</response>
```

So it is kind of working, but not case-insensitive and only based on the beginning of the string.

### The Goal

Make it work for all words contained in the title-field (like in the docs) and make the search case-insensitive.

### Trying to solve it

- I messed around with the title-field: explicitly setting `indexed` and `stored`; setting `multiValued=false`; tried `type=string`.
- I tried all kinds of Terms component parameters
- Tried implementing something similar with facets ([see docs](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Facet_prefix_.28term_suggest.29)) but ran into the same problem.

I'm guessing that it has something to do with the data type or how Solr stores the field, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mats for pointing me in the right direction.

The field type of my title field was indeed wrong and I needed to use another one. While creating my own, I noticed that the default schema.xml has a bunch of predefined field types that do exactly what I wanted.

In my case, I would just set my fields type to text_de:

```java
<field name="title" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Where text_de was predefined like:

```java
<fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to lowercase the contents of a field when indexing, you'll either have to preprocess the content (making it lowercase before indexing it), or easier, use a field type that has a `LowercaseFilter`. That field has to be based on a TextField, but you can use the `KeywordTokenizer` to keep every value as a single token, instead of it being tokenized based on whitespace or something similar.

The terms handler just looks for tokens that match, so by using a KeywordTokenizer, you keep everything as a single token, and the LowercaseFilter makes sure that the indexed token is kept exclusively in lowercase.

If you however *want* to split each term in the content into its own token, i.e. apricots, is, kind, etc., use a WhitespaceTokenizer or the StandardTokenizer, together with a LowercaseFilter.